# How to obtain a tight diagram with standaloneframe?

Tags: beamer, pstricks, standalone, preview

In order to avoid writing the following code, I need to use overlays provided by `beamer`.

### Unpleasant Code

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}    

    \begin{pspicture}(6,6)
        \pnode(0,0){A}
        \pnode(6,0){B}
        \pnode(6,6){C}
        \pnode(0,6){D}
        \pnode(1,1){P}
        \pnode(5,1){Q}
        \pnode(3,5){R}
        \pspolygon*[linecolor=red](A)(B)(Q)(P)
     \end{pspicture}
        
     \begin{pspicture}(6,6)
        \pnode(0,0){A}
        \pnode(6,0){B}
        \pnode(6,6){C}
        \pnode(0,6){D}
        \pnode(1,1){P}
        \pnode(5,1){Q}
        \pnode(3,5){R}
        \pspolygon*[linecolor=red](A)(B)(Q)(P)
        \pspolygon*[linecolor=green](B)(C)(R)(Q)
     \end{pspicture}
        
     \begin{pspicture}(6,6)
        \pnode(0,0){A}
        \pnode(6,0){B}
        \pnode(6,6){C}
        \pnode(0,6){D}
        \pnode(1,1){P}
        \pnode(5,1){Q}
        \pnode(3,5){R}
        \pspolygon*[linecolor=red](A)(B)(Q)(P)
        \pspolygon*[linecolor=green](B)(C)(R)(Q)
        \pspolygon*[linecolor=blue](C)(D)(R)}
     \end{pspicture}
        
     \begin{pspicture}(6,6)
        \pnode(0,0){A}
        \pnode(6,0){B}
        \pnode(6,6){C}
        \pnode(0,6){D}
        \pnode(1,1){P}
        \pnode(5,1){Q}
        \pnode(3,5){R}
        \pspolygon*[linecolor=red](A)(B)(Q)(P)
        \pspolygon*[linecolor=green](B)(C)(R)(Q)
        \pspolygon*[linecolor=blue](C)(D)(R)}
        \pspolygon*[linecolor=yellow](D)(A)(P)(R)
     \end{pspicture}
        
     \begin{pspicture}(6,6)
        \pnode(0,0){A}
        \pnode(6,0){B}
        \pnode(6,6){C}
        \pnode(0,6){D}
        \pnode(1,1){P}
        \pnode(5,1){Q}
        \pnode(3,5){R}
        \psclip{\pscircle[linestyle=none,dimen=middle](3,3){3}}
        \pspolygon*[linecolor=red](A)(B)(Q)(P)
        \pspolygon*[linecolor=green](B)(C)(R)(Q)
        \pspolygon*[linecolor=blue](C)(D)(R)}
        \pspolygon*[linecolor=yellow](D)(A)(P)(R)
        \endpsclip
     \end{pspicture}
 
\end{document}
```

In the past, I  used `beamer` document class and `preview` package as follows. Unfortunately, the code is now no longer compilable.

### Legacy Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=0pt
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}

\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}
    \begin{pspicture}(6,6)
        \pnode(0,0){A}
        \pnode(6,0){B}
        \pnode(6,6){C}
        \pnode(0,6){D}
        \pnode(1,1){P}
        \pnode(5,1){Q}
        \pnode(3,5){R}
        \only<5>{\psclip{\pscircle[linestyle=none,dimen=middle](3,3){3}}}
        \only<1->{\pspolygon*[linecolor=red](A)(B)(Q)(P)}
        \only<2->{\pspolygon*[linecolor=green](B)(C)(R)(Q)}
        \only<3->{\pspolygon*[linecolor=blue](C)(D)(R)}
        \only<4->{\pspolygon*[linecolor=yellow](D)(A)(P)(R)}
       \only<5>{\endpsclip}
     \end{pspicture}
\end{frame}    
\end{document}
```

Having read `standalone`'s confusing documentation (most sentences are hard to understand), I come with the following idea. However, I want to trim the surrounding whitespaces. How to get a tight diagram?

### Modern Code

```
\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\standaloneenv{pspicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{standaloneframe}
    \begin{pspicture}(6,6)
        \pnode(0,0){A}
        \pnode(6,0){B}
        \pnode(6,6){C}
        \pnode(0,6){D}
        \pnode(1,1){P}
        \pnode(5,1){Q}
        \pnode(3,5){R}
        \only<5>{\psclip{\pscircle[linestyle=none,dimen=middle](3,3){3}}}
        \only<1->{\pspolygon*[linecolor=red](A)(B)(Q)(P)}
        \only<2->{\pspolygon*[linecolor=green](B)(C)(R)(Q)}
        \only<3->{\pspolygon*[linecolor=blue](C)(D)(R)}
        \only<4->{\pspolygon*[linecolor=yellow](D)(A)(P)(R)}
       \only<5>{\endpsclip}
     \end{pspicture}
\end{standaloneframe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need a bounty of 500?

Comment: I saw your other bounty. But the problem is not old, the code in the other question worked in 2018, it then broke later again. The space here are added by the beamer option, I would suggest to keep the document simple and to create the pictures without beamer and \only.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Overlays  provided by `beamer` are very useful to simplify code to create animations. The code becomes more  understandable with overlays `\only`.

Comment: yes, I understand that.  But the complication beamer adds here is imho not worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a workaround, I don't know if it could be helpful. I'm using `geometry` to set the paper dimensions and then with a `\foreach` and a couple of `\ifnum`s I simulate the behavior of the `\only` commands (I suppose you can create a 'only' macro). I made the drawing with tikz, because I'm not familiar with pstricks, but I think that the same approach would work with pstricks too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage   {geometry}
\usepackage   {tikz}

% patper dimensions, style
\geometry {paperwidth=60mm}
\geometry {paperheight=60mm}
\geometry {margin=0mm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\foreach\i in {1,...,5}
{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (6,0);
  \coordinate (C) at (6,6);
  \coordinate (D) at (0,6);
  \coordinate (P) at (1,1);
  \coordinate (Q) at (5,1);
  \coordinate (R) at (3,5);
  \useasboundingbox (A) rectangle (C);
  \ifnum \i = 5
    \clip (3,3) circle (3);
  \fi
  \fill[red]      (A) -- (B) -- (Q) -- (P) -- cycle;
  \ifnum \i > 1
    \fill[green]  (B) -- (C) -- (R) -- (Q) -- cycle;
  \fi
  \ifnum \i > 2
    \fill[blue]   (C) -- (D) -- (R) -- cycle;
  \fi
  \ifnum \i > 3
    \fill[yellow] (D) -- (A) -- (P) -- (R) -- cycle;
  \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \clearpage
}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Another idea, closer to the OP approach (I think). Using `beamer` and `beamerposter` to set paper dimensions. I had to play a little with the vertical spacing because there was an annoying "millimeter" of white space above. There are overfull warnings too.

```
\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}
\usepackage[size=custom,width=6,height=6]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamersize    {text margin left=0cm}
\standaloneenv    {tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{standaloneframe}
\vspace*{-0.35mm}%  This number? Trial and error...
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (6,0);
  \coordinate (C) at (6,6);
  \coordinate (D) at (0,6);
  \coordinate (P) at (1,1);
  \coordinate (Q) at (5,1);
  \coordinate (R) at (3,5);
  \useasboundingbox (A) rectangle (C);
  \only<5> {\clip (3,3) circle (3);}
  \fill[red] (A) -- (B) -- (Q) -- (P) -- cycle;
  \only<2->{\fill[green]  (B) -- (C) -- (R) -- (Q) -- cycle;}
  \only<3->{\fill[blue]   (C) -- (D) -- (R) -- cycle;}
  \only<4->{\fill[yellow] (D) -- (A) -- (P) -- (R) -- cycle;}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{standaloneframe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If there is no other solution, I will accept this proposal. But not the `geometry` one. :-)

Comment: Thank you for you last edit. Doing trial and error should be my very last resort.

Comment: @KimJongUn, yeah, I agree. I don't like it either, but perhaps this spacing problem can be corrected in some other way (I don't know how) and other user can point in the good direction.

Answer (score 1):

The last resort inspired by Juan Castaño's answer.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}    
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,...,5}{%        
     \begin{pspicture}(6,6)
        \pnode(0,0){A}
        \pnode(6,0){B}
        \pnode(6,6){C}
        \pnode(0,6){D}
        \pnode(1,1){P}
        \pnode(5,1){Q}
        \pnode(3,5){R}
        %
        \ifnum\i=5\relax
            \psclip{\pscircle[linestyle=none,dimen=middle](3,3){3}}
        \fi
        %
            \pspolygon*[linecolor=red](A)(B)(Q)(P)
        %
        \ifnum\i>1\relax
            \pspolygon*[linecolor=green](B)(C)(R)(Q)
        \fi
        %
        \ifnum\i>2\relax
            \pspolygon*[linecolor=blue](C)(D)(R)
        \fi
        %
        \ifnum\i>3\relax
            \pspolygon*[linecolor=yellow](D)(A)(P)(R)
        \fi
        %
        \ifnum\i=5\relax
            \endpsclip
        \fi
     \end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```